# How to count and display objects in relation ManyToMany in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

I have a simple model with news and categories:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    slug = models.SlugField()

class News(models.Model):
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    title = models.CharField()
    slug = models.SlugField()
    text = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
```

I want to count news for each category and display it on the website, like this:

```
Sport (5)
School (4)
Films (6)
Computer (2)
etc...
```

How can I do this??

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out annotate() function from Django 1.1.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#topics-db-aggregation

Example (from that URL above):

```
>>> q = Book.objects.annotate(num_authors=Count('authors'))
>>> q[0].num_authors
2
>>> q[1].num_authors
1
```

Comment: I tried this, but i got AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'annotate'

Comment: Category.objects.all().annotate(num_news = Count('news_set'))

Answer (score 1):

Very simple:

```
>>> for category in Category.objects.all():
...     print category.name, category.news_set.count()
```