# variable length many to many

Tags: django, manytomanyfield

I want to know how to count the number of "keys" a "keyboard"

```
class Key(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

class Keyboard(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    keys = models.ManyToManyField(Key)
```

I found a similar question but do not know if it can be modified for what I need, which is how many eleementos form a ManyToMany

[count values from manytomanyfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528927/count-values-from-manytomanyfield/31923925#31923925)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the count of `keys` objects associated with a `Keyboard` instance, you can use `.count()`

`keyboard_object.keys.all()` gives the associated `Key` instances for a `keyboard_object`.

We now apply `.count()` on it to get the number of `Key` objects associated with it.

```
keyboard_object.keys.all().count() # gives the count
```

(Even `keyboard_object.keys.count()` will work unless the default `Key` queryset is changed.)

Comment: in addition, unless you change the default queryset of the `Key` model, you can avoid the `.all()` and just do `keyboard_object.keys.count() ` :)