# Django - Number of instance in a related ManyToManyField for a given queryset

Tags: django

I would like to know how many maps are related by a ManyToManyField to a queryset, or said differently, **how many maps have at least one of the shapefiles as layer.**

models.py:

```
class Map(models.Model):
    layers = models.ManyToManyField(Shapefile)

class Shapefile(models.Model):
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

views.py:

```
shapefiles = Shapefile.objects.filter(created_by=request.user)
map_instances = Map.objects... ???
```

example:

```
shape1 = Shapefile(filename = 'shape1')
shape2 = Shapefile(filename = 'shape2')
shape3 = Shapefile(filename = 'shape3')
map1 = Map(name = 'map1')

map1.layers.add(shape1)
map1.layers.add(shape2)
map1.layers.add(shape3)

shapefiles = Shapefile.objects.all()
map_instance = [shape.map_set.count() for shape in shapefiles]
print map_instance
>>>[1,1,1]
print sum(map_instance)
>>> 3
```

or alternatively I could do:

```
map_instance = Map.objects.filter(layers__in=shapefiles)
print map_instance.count()
>>>3
```

for my needs, the map_instance should return 1 map because there is only one map instance that contains the 3 shapefiles. I just dont get how to make it works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for:

```
from django.db.models import Count

maps_with_one_or_more_layer = Map.objects.all().annotate(Count('layers')).filter(layers__count__gte=1)

how_many = maps_with_one_or_more_layers.count()
```

Docs: [QuerySet API reference - Annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#annotate)

Answer (score 0):

```
map_instances = shapefiles.count()
```

But to be more in the style of Django you can create a manager for your model:

```
class ShapefileManager(models.Manager):
    def map_instances(self, user):
        return self.filter(created_by=user).count()

class Shapefile(models.Model):
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    objects = ShapefileManager()

number = Shapefile.objects.map_instances(request.user)
```

**EDIT**: Sorry, missunterstood your question. But I think this link are what you need, it is a simillar issue:

1. [count values from manytomanyfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528927/count-values-from-manytomanyfield)
2. [How to count and display objects in relation ManyToMany in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773504/how-to-count-and-display-objects-in-relation-manytomany-in-django)

Comment: Hi! I want to count the number of `Map` that are related to shapefiles, not the number of `Shapefile` instance in the shapefiles queryset

Comment: sorry, missunterstood your question. does the links in my edit help you?

Comment: this is close but not exactly what im looking for... see edits